# Can I determine what the correlation matrix is if I have regression coefficients and standard errors?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, variance, covariance

I am trying to reverse engineer a manuscript and was wondering if I can get a correlation matrix or the covariance-variance matrix from values reported in a paper. Can I use the reported regression coefficients along with the means and standard deviations to put together a covariance/variance matrix or the correlation matrix?

I know that you can use vcov in R to extract the variance/covariance matrix from a linear model but I am uncertain to the mechanics behind this process and what R is using to calculate this.

Comment: NO, regression coefficients, means and sds is not enough to calculate the correlations.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for the comment, what would you need? Or is it even possible to use any descriptives and coefficients to get at the correlation matrix?

Comment: You would need, in addition, all the variances and cross-correlations of the predictors $X$.

Comment: **A simple counting argument highlights the impossibility:** the covariance matrix of $p$ estimates is an element of a manifold of $p(p+1)/2$ dimensions, whereas three statistics per variable will specify a submanifold of codimension no greater than $3p.$ Thus, when $p\gt 5$ there (generically) will not be a unique solution. (In fact only the standard errors of estimate give you information about covariances, so the problem is insoluble when $p\gt 1.$)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you again for clarifying. I have one final question, could I use an estimation procedure to estimate the likely covariance matrix. For example,  use MCMC?